# send mail and show delivery message in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

how  i can show delivery message in asp.net? 
I use this code for my job but this code no reply me. because i want show message delivery

```
 public string  sendemail(String strFrom, string strTo, string strSubject, string strBody)
 {
        string delivery;
        Array arrToArray;
        char[] splitter = { ';' };
        arrToArray = strTo.Split(splitter);
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();

            mm.From = new MailAddress(strFrom);

        mm.Subject = strSubject;
        mm.Body = strBody;
        //mm.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHTML;

            mm.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("toMail@yahoo.com");


        foreach (string s in arrToArray)
        {
            mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(s));
        }

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true; //Depending on server SSL Settings true/false
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "fromMail@yahoo.com";
            NetworkCred.Password = "pass";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;//Specify your port No;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
            delivery  = mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions.ToString();



        }
        catch
        {
            mm.Dispose(); 
            smtp = null;
            delivery = mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions.ToString();

        }
        return delivery;

    }

    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread threadSendMails;
        threadSendMails = new Thread(delegate()
        {
          Label1.Text  =  sendemail("fromMail@yahoo.com", "toMail@yahoo.com", "Hello", "<p>Body</p>");

        });
        threadSendMails.IsBackground = false ;
        threadSendMails.Start();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the design of the SMTP protocol you cannot be sure that a message has actually arrived at the recepient. You can only be sure that the server has accepted the message. The delivery notification is only implemented in some target mail servers and read notifications are mostly a client thing. If they are written they will be sent via mail to the sender's address. To catch those, you need to monitor a POP3 or IMAP box, or whatever you have.

Additionally: You should think of not using a thread - this might easily lead to hard to to debug weird behaviour.

Comment: if i do not use thread then sending email take some times and user should wait until mail send. my gold of using thread is user do other action when mail sending

Comment: @Shima I've written myself a little program that uses a directory containing files describing the mails. For each file it creates a mail. I'm using that tool from the web, several scheduled jobs, so I could fine tune the mail processing (limiting to a certain number of mails per minute, etc.). You could do something similar, but I would propose that you only do this if you have a very high number of mails or special requirements (as I had). In general ilyabreev is correct, sending a mail (without a big attachment) is usually fast

Comment: can you get me your program?

Comment: Sorry, as I have written this for my employer I'm not allowed to pass it along. But you could have a look into https://code.google.com/p/mailsend/. Maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to send e-mail in the separate thread.
Instead you can just call `sendemail` or another method that implements email sending in the `btnSend_click` event handler.

Also there is no synchronously way to show delivery message of email you sent.

If you want just to show the success message to your website user then you need to declare some `asp:Label` control in markup file (.aspx), make it invisible by default, and show it in your `btnSend_click` just like that:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sendemail("fromMail@yahoo.com", "toMail@yahoo.com", "Hello", "<p>Body</p>");
    Label1.Visible = true;
    // assuming you have asp:Label control with ID "Label1" 
    // and "Visible" property set to false
}
```

Comment: if i do not use thread then sending email take some times and user should wait until mail send. my gold of using thread is user do other action when mail sending.

Comment: You're on the right way with user experience but sending email is not a time consuming operation. You won't get any benefit from that.